# How to write a Perl script to replace duplicate words

Tags: perl, t-sql

How can I formulate a command-line Perl script to replace all duplicate words with chosen aliases.  Currently I have a T-SQL query with about 1000 lines.  But because this query doesn't use any aliases, it is difficult to understand and visualize.  So I go through it by hand and convert table names to aliases.

But it would be more efficient to have a Perl script do this for me.  Can you either advise how I might do this via Perl or else if you know of a SQL tool that can do it instead?

Here is what I tried:

```
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\bin>perl -pi.orig -we 's/\bV_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION\b/A/g' test.sql
Useless use of a constant (s/\bV_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION\b/A/g) in void context at -e
line 1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace a table name like `business_interaction_shoptype_whatnot` with `wtf`, do the following on your SQL file:

```
perl -pi.orig -we 's/\bbusiness_interaction_shoptype_whatnot\b/wtf/g' wtf.sql
```

This will mofify the input file in-place while storing a pristine copy in `wtf.sql.orig`.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work for me.  I  probably formulated it wrong.  Can you see where I performed wrong logic:

Comment: @salvationishere - You're on Windows cmd.exe, so you need to replace the single quotes with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I take your question to mean you want a command-line to edit files "on the fly" with, and not a file that you can re-use when you need it.

The -i switch can be used to edit a file in place. The basic formula you are after is:

```
$ perl -i.extension -e CODE FILE
```

For example: perl -i.bak -e 's/find/replace/g' file.txt

Documentation here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html

I would recommend not using a command-line though, especially if legibility is what you are after. I am not sure what kind of text you are replacing, so it is hard to say what the regexp should look like.

```
#!/bin/perl -i.bak
# Notice the "-i" switch

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    s/Case-Sensitive-text/CST/g;
    s/case-insensitive-text/CIT/ig;
    s/\[text inside brackets\]/no_brackets/g;
}
```

This file based script will do the same if called with `script.pl myfile.txt`

ETA:

```
C:\STRAWB~1\perl\bin>perl -pi.orig -we 's/\bV_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION\b/A/g' test.sql
Useless use of a constant (s/\bV_QXP_ALL_EXCEPTION\b/A/g) in void context at -e
line 1.
```

Why are you messing around inside the perl binary folder? =)

In Windows, you use the double quote instead of single quote when doing command line stuff... for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for all of the details.  But Michael's solution was just what I was looking for.

Comment: It's the same solution. ;) If this is something you do often, I would recommend creating a script file with really tight regexps. Good luck!